# How to run safari in protractor using selenium 2.47.1 jar?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

How to run safari 5.1.7 browser(windows machine) in protractor using selenium 2.47.1 jar?

I need to run safari 5.1.7 browser(windows machine) in protractor using selenium 2.47.1 jar.

Can someone help on this?
From where I need to install the safari driver?(Please provide the link)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible. Safari driver doesn't support safari browser on **WINDOWS** machine and is applicable only for **OS X**. Here's the link that explains it

- [Platforms supported by Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp)

. However if you want to try it for OSX then here's a detailed wiki page for safari driver usage with selenium -

- [Safari Driver with Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver)

You must be able to use it for protractor too. Download the extension file **SafariDriver.safariextz** for safari from the above mentioned link and then install it. Only difference would be to use it with Javascript. Add in the browser name in your conf.js file -

```
'browserName': 'safari'
```

If you are still facing issues, please refer to this [detailed link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7933#c23) for help. Hope it helps.